# Baked normal map/nodes creating incorrect shading at seams (Cycles)

Tags: shaders, normals, normal-map

Many questions have been asked about this, and I tried all their answers, and nothing for me has gotten rid of this error.

[I've been following this video for the skin shader.](https://youtu.be/DKJpAsyExY4)

I baked a normals map for my retopology character. I made tons of textures, and shaders, and now that I'm ready to render in Cycles, an inverted-like shade has become visible at the seams, like an inverted checkered board.

[image]

It still shows in the final render as well, and Flat/Smooth shading won't change anything either.

[image]

How is this issue caused, and how do I fix it?

**EDIT:**

A view of the normal map as a texture, without any normal map displacement.

[image]

**EDIT 2:**

[Here are a few more textures to reference from.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hQkDE.jpg)

**EDIT 3:**
I changed the Normal Map Node's Tangent Space to Object and World, as well as the others, and it fixed the odd shading, but it left lines where the seams are. As well as the lines, it completely messed up my normal and displacement maps on the front. The best overall look (except these awful shading lines/boxes) is the Tangent Space.

**EDIT 4:** [Normal maps/settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2zuCV.jpg)
Old, as in the one used in all other pictures, new as in just out of the oven.

Comment: Do you have splits in your geometry at those seams?

Comment: Splits? No, all vertices are merged together except the eye sockets (Not visible at this angle, and not a problem) and the bottom of the neck.

Comment: Looks like the image map is not tiled to match the seems. check to see that the image edges match up.

Comment: Added an image. The normal map as a texture appears fine.

Comment: clean/delete the seam with in the UV editor under options tab

Comment: Where is the options Tab located? I found on on the 'T' popup, but has no clean/delete options in the UV image editor.

Comment: in the UV editor side panel TOOLS tab at the bottom of the panel

Comment: That didn't change anything. With or without the seams, the bad shading is still shown.

Comment: I'm sorry, back to my first answer. What dose the texture map look like?

Comment: Texture map? The skin diffuse? I took a few, [take a look here.](https://imgur.com/a/Fygy8)

Comment: Try muting either the bump node or the normal map node and see if the seams go away.

Comment: Yes, they go away without the bump/normal node setup. Specifically, only without the Normal Map node.

Comment: Created in Blender Render mode, selecting the low poly mesh then shift select high poly. Bake settings = mode to Normals, Normal Space: Tangent, Selected to Active, Clear, Margin 6px. Distance: 10, Bias: .001. Split: Automatic.

Comment: Sorry, didn't edit my comment soon enough, I meant high poly then low poly.

Comment: In general seam should be visible on the normal map itself, but be invisible on shading, see https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/16354/why-normal-map-baking-break-at-uv-seams. As I see islands aren't intersecting on UV map, but looks like for some reason tangent space treats those seams incorrectly (because according to UV map there should be seams on map itself visible). Try setting Bias to 0. Try checking if islands on UV map aren't placed somewhere next to each other. Other than that create simple version of the model and [share it here](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/)

Comment: Silly enough, setting the Bias to 0 did fix the shading issue. If you'd like, please post that comment in an answer and explain why this occurs. I'd like to know why.

Comment: Well, Bias controls one side of what will be baked, Distance is for another. While it's clear why Bias removes some details from highpoly which didn't manage to fit, it doesn't really explain seam in the middle. My only guess is that for some reason it interferes with UV map creating difference between normal map on one side of UV island and another one. See some info about differences between them https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/55279/whats-the-difference-between-bias-and-distance. You can add answer just as well